# How does pgAdmin show geo visualization?

Tags: postgis, pgadmin

I've started to add some geo-data to a table (postgis enabled database) and I just saw I can visualize the point on a integrated leaflet.

But how does it work ? Is pgAdmin querying an API or a webservice ? Is this leaflet integrated with the postgis setup ?

I'm just begining with postgis so I have no idea about this magic ^^

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the different components are clearly defined and separated, the magic goes away....

Simplifying a bit, we have:

**Postrgres**, the database that contains your data.

**PostGIS** is an extension for Postgres that allows you to store (and work with) geometries.

**PGAdmin** is a viewer for Postgres that runs in a webbrowser.

**Leaflet** is a javascript library used to display spatial data.

**OpenStreetMap** is an open-source dataset that can be used as a basemap.

So, `PGAdmin` runs in the browser and can run any javascript code. It makes use of this to load the `Leaflet` library. When the geometry viewer is used, `PGAdmin` creates a Leaflet map, tells it to display the public `OpenStreetMap` basemap and overlay your data from your table.